# Connectify and Galaxy Grand duos android 4.2.2 hotspot connectivity issue

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, connectify

When using connectify for the first or after a long time, the mobile connects just fine to the hotspot untill 2-3 days pass by and it disconnects and stops displaying the name of the network in the wifi networks list. I tried switching off and then on the network and my mobile's wifi but no good. The mobile does display other networks but not the one it was using for the past 2-3 days.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution finally. It so happens that there are 2 modes i.e the 2GHz and the 5GHz in a wifi adapter and the my mobile works in just one of them i.e. the 2 GHz mode.

All we need to do is change the mode of operation of our system or hotspot host.

For that:

1. Go to Device Manager.
2. Go to Network Adapter.
3. Acc. to my system I right clicked on the adapter by the name of
   Intel Centrino Advanced N-6235 and went to properties
4. Go to Advanced. For those who want to know how the adapter
   properties look like by hit and trial here is a snapshot of the
   advanced tab of properties.

[image]

5. Choose "Preferred Band" and change it to 5.2GHz.
6. Click Okay and restart your hotspot the job is done !